# How to add CSS animation to squeeze during the transition of its direction?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, css-animations, css-transitions

Using vue3, tailwind3

**The goal:** When clicking yearly or monthly, the white background is to transition in the direction of the newly selected option and have a liquid/squeeze motion so it feels more fluid

**The challenge:** Going monthly to yearly looks great! But going yearly to monthly does not, even though using the same animation with opposite transitions doesn't give the same effect.

[image: monthly-yearly]

[Video animation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yMwfC-chWiXkjrGxTOhMoIX5j7r_lXJ5/view?usp=sharing)

**Yearly to monthly**, you can see how it goes off the right side first:

[image: yearly-to-monthly]

The transition doesn't squeeze: (obv because the 1.5 scaleX, but the glitch of it going off the right side messes this up)

[image: yearly-to-monthly-2]

**Monthly to yearly** has the correct squeeze transition:

[image: monthly-to-yearly]

You might say, why not do scaleX 1.5 on the origin right, but it glitches and creates an even worse effect. This CSS was the only way that looks somewhat normal, aside from it cutting off the side.

```css
body {
  background: rgb(147 51 234)
}

.animate-slide-and-squeeze {
  animation: slide-and-squeeze 0.7s forwards;
}

.animate-slide-and-expand {
  animation: slide-and-expand 0.4s forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-and-squeeze {
  0% {
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: translateX(0) scaleX(1.5);
  }
  50% {
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: translateX(100%) scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: translateX(100%) scaleX(1);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-and-expand {
  0% {
    transform-origin: right;
    transform: translateX(100%) scaleX(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform-origin: right;
    transform: translateX(100%) scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: right;
    transform: translateX(0) scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/petite-vue" defer init></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>


<div v-scope="{ planRate: 'Yearly' }" class="flex justify-center items-center mt-8">
  <div class="flex bg-gray-200/[0.2] rounded-full transition-all duration-500 overflow-hidden relative p-1 shadow">
    <div class="absolute top-0 left-0 h-full transition-all ease-in-out duration-500 transform p-1" :class="{
            'animate-slide-and-squeeze': planRate === 'Yearly',
            'animate-slide-and-expand ': planRate === 'Monthly'
        }" :style="{ width: planRate === 'Monthly' ? 'calc(50% + 0.5rem)' : 'calc(50%)'}">
      <div class="w-full h-full rounded-full bg-white indicator"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="text-sm font-medium rounded-full py-2 px-6 relative z-10 transition-colors duration-200" :class="planRate === 'Monthly' ? 'text-black delay-200' : 'text-white'" @click="planRate = 'Monthly'">Monthly</button>
    <button type="button" class="text-sm font-medium rounded-full py-2 px-6 relative z-10 transition-colors duration-500 delay-100" :class="planRate === 'Yearly' ? 'text-black' : 'text-white'" @click="planRate = 'Yearly'">Yearly</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should make your code a snippet, it would allow others to simply run the animations themselves and make the edits necessary. I would suggest an edit myself, but StackOverflow is not allowing edits for some reason.

Comment: @Jordan Thanks, thats good feedback, I'll need to look up how to do the embed snippets because that would def be easier for everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue here is really around the width that was being set based on the state. Because of the way that Vue re-renders, the `width` was getting added and the transition is being run, but they aren't happening concurrently. So, it's stretching off the edge was the width getting adjusted, then the animation running.

The trick here was to add the width into the animation so that it would adjust it as well as adjusting the transforms.

I made a few tweaks to the way you had it — some just removing unneeded tailwind classes. That said, I believe I've got it working the way that you would like. The animations look the same going back and forth. You'll probably want to set some initial CSS that matches the initial state styles. So it doesn't animate on load.

```css
body {
  background: rgb(147 51 234)
}

.animate-slide-and-squeeze {
  animation: slide-and-squeeze 0.7s forwards;
}

.animate-slide-and-expand {
  animation: slide-and-expand 0.7s forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-and-squeeze {
  0% {
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: translateX(0) scaleX(1.5);
  }
  50% {
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: translateX(100%) scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: left;
    transform: translateX(100%) scaleX(1);
  }
}

@keyframes slide-and-expand {
  0% {
    transform-origin: right;
    transform: translateX(100%) scaleX(1.5);
    width: 50%;
  }
  50% {
    transform-origin: right;
    transform: translateX(0) scaleX(1);
    width: calc(50% + 0.5rem);
  }
  100% {
    transform-origin: right;
    transform: translateX(0) scaleX(1);
    width: calc(50% + 0.5rem);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/petite-vue" defer init></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>


<div v-scope="{ planRate: 'Yearly' }" class="flex justify-center items-center mt-8">
  <div class="flex bg-gray-200/[0.2] rounded-full transition-all duration-500 overflow-hidden relative p-1 shadow">
    <div class="absolute top-0 left-0 h-full p-1 w-1/2" :class="{
            'animate-slide-and-squeeze': planRate === 'Yearly',
            'animate-slide-and-expand ': planRate === 'Monthly'
        }">
      <div class="w-full h-full rounded-full bg-white"></div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="flex-1 text-sm font-medium rounded-full py-2 px-6 relative z-10 transition-colors duration-200" :class="planRate === 'Monthly' ? 'text-black delay-200' : 'text-white'" @click="planRate = 'Monthly'">Monthly</button>
    <button type="button" class="flex-1 text-sm font-medium rounded-full py-2 px-6 relative z-10 transition-colors duration-200" :class="planRate === 'Yearly' ? 'text-black' : 'text-white'" @click="planRate = 'Yearly'">Yearly</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: I used `petite-vue` for the sake of the demo, but it will be the same in Vue 3.